# Calculate average grade for x objects of a class

Tags: java, class, object

Can anybody give me a clue about how to calculate the average grade of all the objects from a class Student?

My class student contains:

```
String name // of student
String [] courses // the array that contains all the courses for each student
Int [] grades // the array that contains the grades for each student
```

i have created a method that computes the average for the single object (student):

```
public double averageGradeStud() {
        double total = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfGrades; i++) {

            total += grades[i];

        }

        return (total / numberOfGrades);
```

But how can I create a method that calculates the average grade for all the students (objects) that have been created?

Comment: Calculate average of [averages of grades] for students.

Answer (score 1):

I assume students are in a collection. You need to iterate through the collection and map your function that calculates student's average grade to each student. At the same time you sum these values up and after the iteration is finished, divide it by number of students:

```
List<Student> students;
double total = 0;
for(Student s : students){
    total += s.averageGradeStud();
}
double averageForAll = total / students.size();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say the most concise way to do it would be to make an ArrayList of your students then make a method that gets their total grade average. Afterwards you could use a for loop to calculate the total for all of the students.

```
 //Example
 int totalGrad = 0;
 for(int i = 0; i < studentList.size(); i++)
 {
     totalGrad += studentList.get(i).getAverageGrade();
     // if you want to then average the totalGrad you can do the following
     totalGrad = (totalGrad / studentList.size());
 }
```